# How do I add (css) class to a custom link to make it current_page_item

Tags: menus, css

As a custom menu item wp doesn't add the class current_page_item

All other links it does?

```
<ul class="nav" id="menu-mainmenu"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-home menu-item-21152" id="menu-item-21152"><a href="http://mydomain/">Home</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type current-menu-item page_item page-item-21154 current_page_item menu-item-21156" id="menu-item-21156"><a href="http://mydomain/">Future TV Guide</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-21153" id="menu-item-21153"><a href="http://mydomain/">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

I would like to show it as an active link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just target .current-menu-item along with .current_page_item?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard for WP to figure that your custom menu item is the active one. They are for external links, after all, so it might not even be your WP install anymore. Since WP generates the menu on every page load it simply tries to figure right then what the active menu item is.

To overcome your isse...firstly, assess if you can do what you need to do without placing a custom menu item. If you still see your WP menu on that 'custom' target, chances are you can add it to the menu by other means.

If, for whatever reason, that's not an option, compare the style classes attached to your `<body>` tag with the ones attached to the menu entry. For instance, if have a page linked that on result shows `page-id-2` on the body tag and `page-item-2` on the menu entry.

Adjust your stylesheet to highlight the combination of that as active, for instance in my case it would be an entry

```
body.page-item-2 #menu-main-menu .page-id-2 {
    whatever: styles;
    are: suitable;
}
```

Also note that you have limited control over at least one entry in the menu items classes by adjusting the menu entry slug.